# Prevent longtable to split cells while using \hline

Tags: line-breaking, longtable

although the question seems to be trivial and to be answered several times, I have not found a solution yet :-( I'm using a `longtable` to describe a set of computer benchmarks. Each benchmark entry consists of rows, a "headline" (name, references), and a "description". Now I do not want `longtable` to split the headline row and the description row, but print them on the same page. This can be done using `\\*`. Now the problem is that I want to have a `\hline` between the headline and the description, but both potential options do not work:

- `\\\hline *` : Latex compile error
- `\\*\hline`  : The headline and the description are split

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Is there anything that resembls a MWE?

Comment: easiest way is to ignore it unless it happens and if it does happen, force a page break after the previous row

Comment: you could make a feature request for longtable v5 but it's been 18 years since longtable v4 came out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `headline` and `description` inside a separate `tabular` inside the same row of `longtable`. You can even make a macro for it like:

```
\newcommand{\benchmark}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
 #1 \\ \midrule
 #2
 \end{tabular}%
 }
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[textheight=3cm]{geometry}   %% 3cm only for demo
\newcommand{\benchmark}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
 #1 \\ \midrule
 #2
 \end{tabular}%
 }
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}l@{}}\toprule[1pt]
  \endfirsthead
  \toprule[1pt]
  \endhead
    \benchmark{Headline}{Some Description}\\\toprule[1pt]
    \benchmark{Headline}{Some Description}\\\toprule[1pt]
    \benchmark{Headline}{Some Description}\\\toprule[1pt]
    \benchmark{Headline}{Some Description}\\\toprule[1pt]
    \benchmark{Headline}{Some Description}\\\toprule[1pt]
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's harder to do this in the general case that the table has multiple columns and you don't know their widths in advance

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True. But for simple cases like this, we can do some circus ;)

Comment: Although I hoped for a "nice" solution, this works, as well :-) Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the extra space in the first line from the second page and beyond, you can replace the second `\toprule[1pt]` (above `\endhead`) by `\specialrule{1pt}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}` [**Source**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609718/142706)