# Unwanted extra vertical space after header using longtable in memoir, on continuation pages

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, longtable

The vertical spacing below the rule at the end of the headings is as I expect on page 1 of the table, but on pages 2, 3, etc I get more vertical space.

Is there a fix for this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ChangeLipsumPar{} % Don't want \par at the end of each \parbox in the \longtable
\setlipsumdefault{2} % short enough to get 2 table rows per page

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{150pt}p{150pt}}
Heading & Heading \\ \midrule
\endhead
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule % Extra space above this row
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

EIDT: following the comments, this solves my specific problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ChangeLipsumPar{} % Don't want \par at the end of each \parbox in the \longtable
\setlipsumdefault{2} % short enought to get 2 table rows per page

\newdimen\savebelowrulesep
\savebelowrulesep=\belowrulesep

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{150pt}p{150pt}}
\global\belowrulesep=0pt % Kill the space below \midrule in the header
Heading & Heading \\
\midrule
\endhead
\noalign{\global\belowrulesep=\savebelowrulesep % Restore \midrule ...
\vskip\belowrulesep} % ... and tweak the spacing on the first page
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule % Extra space above this row
\lipsum & \lipsum \\ \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes sorry you have some space frozen into the heading box from the `\midrule` in the heading, but you are also picking up space when breaking at a `\midrule` so you get extra space except at the beginning...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as you point if 3rd \midrule replaced by \hline or just \\ everything is good

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so I could get rid of the space in the header by using `\hline` not `\midrule`, then add some space above the first table line to compensate? Every line in the table ends with `\midrule`.

Comment: @touhami That might fix the MWE, but I don't want to go through a 100-page table finding and editing the last entry on every page!

Comment: @alephzero there is other solutions for now let for example \belowrulesep=0pt

Answer (score 1):

The space comes from the `booktabs` rule in the header which includes vertical space.

You could use a standard `\hline` instead at that position or set `\belowrulesep=0pt` as noted in the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

In your first MWE, replace the line

```
Heading & Heading \\ \midrule
```

By the following one

```
Heading & Heading \\ \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
```

---

##### Explanation

The simplest solution is to eliminate the "double space" caused by breaking at a `\midrule` plus the `\midrule` in the heading, as [David Carlisle pointed out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232963/#comment551562_232963).

I particularly disliked the presented solutions, thus I used `\specialrule` from [`booktabs`](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf#page=6) package to simulate a `\midrule` but without the `\belowrulesep` below it. Then, I exchanged the `\midrule` of the header by this rule (so you must change only one line instead of dozens).

I think this solution is better since you can control the rule width by replacing `\lightrulewidth` with something else like `\heavyrulewidth`, `1em` and so on...

---

##### Exception - splitting long table manually with `\pagebreak`

This approach will work as long as you don't split the long table manually (using `\pagebreak`) at some point, because it will cause the first line of the next page to touch the header.

In case you need to do so, you can "restore" the missing space by adding it manually with `\addlinespace[<width>]`.

In short, instead of using only `\pagebreak`, you must split the long table using:

```
\pagebreak\addlinespace[\belowrulesep]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{2} % short enough to get 2 table rows per page

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Table Title},
]{
  colspec={p{150pt}p{150pt}},
  rowhead = 1,
}
\toprule
  Heading & Heading \\
\midrule
  \lipsum & \lipsum \\
\midrule
  \lipsum & \lipsum \\
\midrule
  \lipsum & \lipsum \\
\midrule
  \lipsum & \lipsum \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]